# How can I refactor this in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using Laravel framework however, this answer should be able to be answered without the framework knowledge.

I have a database table called images. For my website, each video has a main video image, a smaller feature image, a landscape and portrait image, gallery_six (which is a picture with 6 pictures on it). Every other image is classed as a normal_image.

The table look like this:

```
id | gallery_id | link | alt | video_image | feature_image | gallery_landscape | gallery_portrait | gallery_six | normal_image
```

Now when I create the gallery, I am trying to insert the records into the database but my code just looks messy and I'm unsure how I could refactor this.

When my post request comes through to the controller it looks like this:

```
array(
    [video_image_link] => 'link'
    [video_image_alt] => 'alt'
    [feature_image_link] => 'link'
    [feature_image_alt] => 'alt'
    [gallery_landscape_image_link] => 'link'
    [gallery_landscape_image_alt] => 'alt'
    [gallery_portrait_image_link] => 'link'
    [gallery_portrait_image_alt] => 'alt'
)
```

In my method I'm doing this:

```
public static function uploadMainImages($request,$gallery_id)
{
    //upload video image
    Image::create([
        'gallery_id'=>$gallery_id,
        'link'=>$request['video_image_link'],
        'alt'=>$request['video_image_alt'],
        'video_image'=>1,
        'feature_image'=>0,
        'gallery_landscape'=>0,
        'gallery_portrait'=>0,
        'gallery_six'=>0,
        'normal_image'=>0,
    ]);
    //upload feature image
    Image::create([
        'gallery_id'=>$gallery_id,
        'link'=>$request['feature_image_link'],
        'alt'=>$request['feature_image_alt'],
        'video_image'=>0,
        'feature_image'=>1,
        'gallery_landscape'=>0,
        'gallery_portrait'=>0,
        'gallery_six'=>0,
        'normal_image'=>0,
    ]);
```

And so on ...

Is there a better way for me to do this, without changing the database and only going with the post data in its current form?

Comment: If this looks messy to you... Then you haven't lived long enough to see yourself become a programmer!

Comment: Does that mean it isn't messy?

Comment: Not at all! just make the code work properly.

Comment: Laravel, static methods and coupling to `Image`, accepting request directly in something that should be in the domain layer... these are all some things you should reconsider.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static function uploadMainImages($request,$gallery_id) {
    createImg($gallery_id, $request['video_image_link'], $request['video_image_alt'], "video_image");
    createImg($gallery_id, $request['feature_image_link'], $request['feature_image_alt'], "feature_image");
    createImg($gallery_id, $request['gallery_landscape_image_link'], $request['gallery_landscape_image_alt'], "gallery_landscape");
    createImg($gallery_id, $request['gallery_portrait_image_link'], $request['gallery_portrait_image_alt'], "gallery_portrait");

}    

function createImg($id, $link, $alt, $type) {
    $video_image = ($type == "video_image" ? 1 : 0);
    $feature_image = ($type == "feature_image" ? 1 : 0);
    $gallery_landscape = ($type == "gallery_landscape" ? 1 : 0);
    $gallery_portrait = ($type == "gallery_portrait" ? 1 : 0);
    $gallery_six = ($type == "gallery_six" ? 1 : 0);
    $normal_image = ($type == "normal_image" ? 1 : 0);

    Image::create([
        'gallery_id'=>$id,
        'link'=>$link,
        'alt'=>$alt,
        'video_image'=> $video_image,
        'feature_image'=> $feature_image,
        'gallery_landscape'=> $gallery_landscape,
        'gallery_portrait'=> $gallery_portrait,
        'gallery_six'=> $gallery_six,
        'normal_image'=> $normal_image,
    ]);
}
```

Maybe something like this. Use the function to create the image type you want.

Comment: Something like this maybe

Comment: Please provide context surrounding the code which you have supplied.